# how to find major and minor elements in a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
         ID     ref alt refN altN
  Chr1_1369       G   T  351  165
 Chr1_54979       G   A  130  309
Chr1_187626       C   G  319  219
Chr1_196254       C   G  171  364
Chr1_224569       C   T  463   90
Chr1_275670       T   C  271  262
Chr1_305245       A   C  246  285
Chr1_313716       T   C  505   51
```

The "refN" column is the count number of column "ref", and "altN" is the count number for the "alt" column. I would like to create another two columns to hold the major and minor elements (doubled) of "ref" or "alt", respectively, which would be dependent on the comparison between "refN" and "altN". The corresponding doubled elements in "ref" or "alt" would be put in the "major" column if its value in "refN" or "altN" is bigger, while the smaller would be put in "minor". In this case, the expected result is:

```
         ID     ref alt refN altN  major minor
  Chr1_1369       G   T  351  165   GG    TT
 Chr1_54979       G   A  130  309   AA    GG
Chr1_187626       C   G  319  219   CC    GG
Chr1_196254       C   G  171  364   GG    CC
Chr1_224569       C   T  463   90   CC    TT
Chr1_275670       T   C  271  262   TT    CC
Chr1_305245       A   C  246  285   CC    AA
Chr1_313716       T   C  505   51   TT    CC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to select the correct doubled version:

```
dat$major <- ifelse(dat$refN >= dat$altN, paste0(dat$ref, dat$ref), paste0(dat$alt, dat$alt))
dat$minor <- ifelse(dat$refN < dat$altN, paste0(dat$ref, dat$ref), paste0(dat$alt, dat$alt))
dat
#            ID ref alt refN altN major minor
# 1   Chr1_1369   G   T  351  165    GG    TT
# 2  Chr1_54979   G   A  130  309    AA    GG
# 3 Chr1_187626   C   G  319  219    CC    GG
# 4 Chr1_196254   C   G  171  364    GG    CC
# 5 Chr1_224569   C   T  463   90    CC    TT
# 6 Chr1_275670   T   C  271  262    TT    CC
# 7 Chr1_305245   A   C  246  285    CC    AA
# 8 Chr1_313716   T   C  505   51    TT    CC
```

Answer (score 2):

I `paste0()`-ed two copies of the alternates of 'ref' and 'alt' that depended on whether refN was greater or less than altN: I did make this so that the columns were NOT factors. The indexing with a two-column matrix is an R feature:

```
dat$major <- paste0(  dat[ cbind( seq(nrow(dat)), 2+(dat$refN > dat$altN))],
                      dat[ cbind( seq(nrow(dat)), 2+(dat$refN > dat$altN))])
dat$minor <- paste0(  dat[ cbind( seq(nrow(dat)), 2+(dat$refN <= dat$altN))], 
                      dat[ cbind( seq(nrow(dat)), 2+(dat$refN <= dat$altN))])
 dat

       ID ref alt refN altN major minor
1   Chr1_1369   G   T  351  165    TT    GG
2  Chr1_54979   G   A  130  309    GG    AA
3 Chr1_187626   C   G  319  219    GG    CC
4 Chr1_196254   C   G  171  364    CC    GG
5 Chr1_224569   C   T  463   90    TT    CC
6 Chr1_275670   T   C  271  262    CC    TT
7 Chr1_305245   A   C  246  285    AA    CC
8 Chr1_313716   T   C  505   51    CC    TT
```

Comment: the row 4, 6, 7 and 8  in the "major" column are not my expected values. So the minors are also wrong from your output

Comment: Sorry. The test should have been `refN` vs `altN` rather than `ref` vs `alt`. Should work now.

Comment: You could also maybe save running the whole thing twice by concatenating each value to itself using `sub`, for example `dat$major <- sub("(.*)", "\\1\\1", dat[ cbind( seq(nrow(dat)), 2+(dat$refN > dat$altN))])`